# Alternative to NULL check and then OR for optional paramaters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use this pattern for optional filter paramaters in my SQL Stored Procedures

```
            AND  (
                @OptionalParam IS NULL OR
                (
                    Id = @OptionalParam
                )
            )
```

However the OR is not a friend of the query optimizer. Is there a more efficient way to do this without using dynamic SQL

Comment: For 2005, take a look at: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL
Version for SQL 2005 and Earlier](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html). For 2008, take a look at: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL
Version for SQL 2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using COALESCE. Not sure if it will be more efficient.

```
AND Id = Coalesce(@OptionalParam, Id)
```

This will not work if Id itself is null and you are using ANSI nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND ID = ISNULL(@OptionalParam, ID)
```

or you if you had multiple optional parameters can use

```
AND ID = COALESCE(@OptionalParam1, @OptionalParam2, ID)
```

This is definitely faster than using an OR statement.

Like the other answerer mentioned, this will not work if the ID column is null (but then again, the original statement wouldn't either).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
AND Id = CASE WHEN @OptionalParam IS NULL THEN Id ELSE NULL END
```

I doubt this will optimize much better, but there's no `OR` in it.

Alternatively, you could break your query apart into two components -- one with just an `@OptionalParam IS NULL` test and another with an `Id = @OptionalParam` test, then `UNION` them together.  Depending on your data topology this might yield better results.  It could also be significantly worse.